# How can I resolve this issue when I am trying to uninstall django from system?

Tags: django

[image]

First I checked the version of django so I got 3.1.3 but when I tried to uninstall with pip uninstall django it says 'Skipping django as it is not installed'.

Comment: are you using a virtual environment? It might be that you are running pip uninstall outside the virtual environment where Django is installed.

Comment: No i have not created an environment separately

Comment: You might have multiple Python installations. Try `pip3 uninstall django`. What does `where django-admin` say?

Comment: Thanks @alv2017 helping, issue resolved by using where django-admin and deleting from there. And I have understood that django and django-admin are different:)

Answer (score -1):

I checked the image you have added. It shows that you have is *django-admin* installed on your system (not Django itself!). As per description django-admin is a separate package containing Django Admin Extensions: https://github.com/django-xxx/django-admin. All in all it is different package from Django, and having it on your system doesn't imply automatically that you have Django installed as well.

Comment: The `django-admin` executable is part of Django.

Comment: well, the easiest thing to find this out is to type in the command: pip list. :)

Comment: `pip` thinks that `django` is not installed. See the question.

Comment: I agree with that

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk helping, issue resolved by using where django-admin and deleting from there. And I have understood that django and django-admin are different:)

Comment: Now you know how to install django-admin on other people machines :)